# Can I create an Earth Model with the exact size of earth (i.e. radius of 6,371km)? How?

Tags: modeling, dimensions

I am trying to create a real model of earth including core layers and topographic surface but  I need to have it done to scale but when I adjusted the radius of the sphere to 6371km it disappeared from the view no mater how zoomed out I am

Comment: Actually you can bring it back into view if you set the 3D Viewport's _Clipping Start_ to 100 m and _End_ to 100000000 m (100,000,000 that's 100 million), but this is not a good dimension to work with. I would suggest using a smaller scale like the answer does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Blender doesn't handle that kind of scale really well.

You could try adjusting the *Clip End* value under the <kbd>N</kbd> menu > View tab, but I couldn't get this to stop the awful glitching that occurs at such large scale.

I recommend using a smaller scale. Try dividing your number by 1000 (6371 meters instead of kilometers.) With the *Clip End* value at 7000, Blender handled this reasonably well.

If you still have problems, you could make it smaller. It probably won't affect the way it renders. (If you do try to render it, make sure you adjust the *Clip End* on your camera as well!)